# Payment Request API - Pay Cash option

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, w3c, applepay, payment-request-api

Is it possible to add a "Cash on Delivery" option to the Payment Request API ?

Can I solve this problem with `methodData`?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the PRAPI, but what would be the goal in using the Payment Request API for an out-of-bound transaction method? I'd add that fork at a higher level: "Pay by cash or <some electronic means using PRAPI> now!" To answer your question: it seems _not_, given the [standardized-payment-method](https://www.w3.org/TR/payment-method-id/#dfn-standardized-payment-method).

Comment: The goal is that the user can select his shipping address and has a good user experience

Comment: Not a bad goal, but this feels like fitting a square peg into a round hole. The purpose of the PRAPI is to facilitate electronic transactions, not just gather billing address, which is trivial for any form (especially with autofill). As of right now, `basic-card` seems to be the [only one listed in the standard payment method registry](https://w3c.github.io/payment-method-id/#registry).

Answer (score 1):

Cash on delivery is one of most frequently requested features. There is no plan to provide such payment method as a standard AFAIK but an idea to accommodate it as part of Payment Request API user experience exists.

A spec called [Payment Handler API](https://w3c.github.io/payment-handler/) enables anyone to develop their own payment method and its implementing payment app (webpage) as part of Payment Request API (if merchant adds it).

The idea is a merchant can create a cash on delivery payment app and serve it by itself. The payment method simply tells a user that they need to pay upon receiving an item.

That way, you can take advantage of collecting shipping address part of PR API yet using cash on delivery as a payment method.

If you want to try Payment Handler example, visit https://bobpay.xyz and install "Bobpay web payment app" then go to https://rsolomakhin.github.io/pr/bob/ to make payment.

Comment: Thx this is what i was looking for, unfortunately this function does not work on my phone yet (by default settings), so i think i have to wait a bit until i can use it in production